# How to make static methods inheritable?

Tags: typescript

I need to do some meta-programming and have to inherit from a function class wrapper. It works well, except that it won't recognises that static methods were also inherited. They are there, but TypeScript can't see it. How can I make it work

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20method()%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20static%20staticMethod()%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20AConstructor%20%7B%20%0A%20%20new()%3A%20A%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20function%20classA()%3A%20AConstructor%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20A%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20classA()%20%7B%7D%0A%0Anew%20B().method()%0AB.staticMethod()%20%2F%2F%20%3C%3D%20error%20here)

```
class A {
  method() {}
  static staticMethod() {}
}

export interface AConstructor { 
  new(): A
}

export function classA(): AConstructor {
  return A
}

class B extends classA() {}

new B().method()
B.staticMethod() // <= error here
```

Comment: The static methods are properties of the class. And the class is a global function. This makes the static methods namespaced global functions. `static` is not OOP.

Comment: @axiac - In JavaScript (which TypeScript compiles to), `B` inherits `staticMethod` from `A` because `A` is `B`'s prototype (just like `A.prototype` is `B.prototype`'s prototype).

Comment: Yes, so to solve the error instead of making the classA typecasting of A it should be extending A

Comment: @NehaTawar I can't inherit from A directly, I need to do some modifications in that function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The question is about TypeScript (that attempts to put some order in the mess named JavaScript). Sure, it works in JavaScript but it is still not OOP.

Comment: @axiac - All due respect, OOP is a bigger concept than you're allowing for there. Re your comments on JavaScript: I'm not a fan of raising the temperature of a technical discussion in that way. There's no need for it, and it only hampers discourse. Good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not so much with inheritance. Static methods will be accessible on derived classes by default.

Your problem is with the signature of `classA`. It returns just a constructor that returns `A` and no other methods. Use `typeof A` or add the static methods to the interface :

```
class A {
  method() {}
  static staticMethod() {}
}

export interface AConstructor { 
  new(): A
  staticMethod(): void // No static modifier here
}

export function classA(): AConstructor {
  return A
}

class B extends classA() {}

new B().method()
B.staticMethod()
```

This could also work:

```
export function classA(): typeof A {
  return A
}
```

Or just let inference do its job:

```
export function classA() {
  return A
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems like it's not working if class A is generic `class A<I>` do you know if it's possible to make it work for generics too?

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin depends what you want to do with the generics.. this works: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGtAtgUwBcALAewBMAKASnQF8toICwCBLYR5t4AWUNMo009ehjwAPAA4kATgWisAdgTwyAZmGB44AYRKKmMgK7ACs9NAaK8AdyTJqALjj2GTFuz7FyT6ADcSVjJoAHoQ6AA5Ek4PDhxyVjVWVWgiVTwMUQlpOWg1I0VTVn1oUEgIWF9YPQMCY1NzTGwZQiMZRThMjAwyqGgAIWgJFUUyGF6K6nhFIxwAI1VUYW7rGwHqADp8b0EMfo33bi8BaiA

Comment: Yes, but you have to duplicate static method declarations, not a clean solution.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin `typeof A` works as expected and requires no duplication: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGtAtgUwBcALAewBMAKASnQF8toICwCBLYR5t4AWUNMo009ehjwAPAA4kATgWgAzAK4A7YGxIrooSBFjUAXNAIBPSXhIK46BjMJKZW2BlE6o0AELQJBPCrIwbnrU8CpKOABGeDKowhgYKngA7p7UAHT4xOTUGB5pTCzsfFmCQA

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin like I said depends what your priorities are :)